# What's wrong with this virtualbox machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, virtualbox

I've downloaded virtualbox, created a machine and installed a ubuntu image on it. Everything goes fine, until it's time to reboot the machine at the end of installation. It reboots into a blank screen, no errors, and no further prompts, just a blank screen. I'm not sure how to trouble shoot this. Can someone give me some hints?

I'm on Windows7, the latest virtualbox 4.1.4 and `ubuntu-11.10-server-i386.iso`.

I'm on a 64-bit machine, but when I use `server-amd64.iso` it complains about kernel problems and doesn't begin installing the OS. So this is why I'm using the `server-i386.iso`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only blank screen appears, even "Press F12 to select boot device" message is not shown, you have problems with virtuabox installation, try reinstalling it. Try to temporary disable antivirus/firewall on host machine(first one can break virtualbox work, second one can disable local RDP connection, used by virtualbox to display host screen).

Look at VM log files, their place and format are described [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/virtualbox_log_files)

Answer (score 0):

The newer versions of Ubuntu uses a framebuffer that has [problems with many older video cards](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=44979#p202694) and virtualizers.

Hold left shift while booting. Edit grub's boot line, and remove `quiet splash`. Boot up and edit `/etc/default/grub/` to make the changes permanent.

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced the same issue. After lots of scouring on the web, finally realized that virtualization was disabled in BIOS settings which was causing this issue.

Enter BIOS settings, search for Virtualization and Enable it.

Problem solved!! !